# Does this approach on MEDP take into account the multiple differential trails?

Tags: aes, s-boxes, differential-analysis

I was reading [this (chapter 3.1)](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/085.pdf) paper, and the author proposed this method to calculate the MEDP on 2-round AES:

[image]

I cannot fully understand what he is doing but it seems like it iterating over all possible intermediate differentials that lead to (a,b).
Is that really the case?

Comment: Have you looked at Appendix A (it contains a proof, which may be helpful)? By the way, the authors are both female (use she, not he).